# Functional Conway's Game of Life in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming, game-of-life

In this code, I tried to integrate my little knowledge of (and great fascination towards) functional programming. I'd like to make this code more functional, and faster, if that's possible.

```
'use strict';
var insert = require('./insert');

const STEP = 50;
const WIDTH = 200, HEIGHT = 100;
var ptr  = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]];

function init(scr) {
    var cwObj = {
        canvas: document.getElementById(scr),//set up the graphics department
        gMap: new Array(HEIGHT).fill(new Array(WIDTH).fill(0))
    };
    draw(cwObj, ptr, 30, 60);
    step(cwObj.gMap);
    return cwObj;
}

function draw(cwObj, pattern, x = 0, y = 0) {
    if(pattern){//draw pattern to map
        pattern.map(function (cur, i){
            cwObj.gMap[x + i] = insert(cwObj.gMap[x + i], cur, y);
            //insert() is a helper, just inserts at an index 
        });
    }
    var out = '';
    cwObj.gMap.map(function (cur) {     //create a string of active and 
        cur.map(function (cell) {       //inactive cells 
            if(cell) {out += "<b>&#9632;</b>";} else {out += "&#9632;";}
        });
        out += "<br>";
    });
    cwObj.canvas.innerHTML = out;  //put it in the HTML
}

function step (gm){
    return gm.map(function (cur, y) {
        return cur.map(function (cell, x){
            var n = getNb(gm, x, y);
            n = cell === 1 ? n - 1 : n;//getNb includes the cell itself
            return n === 3 ? 1 : ((n === 2 && cell === 1) ? 1 : 0);//rules
        });
    });
}

function getNb (gm, x, y){
    var w = WIDTH, h = HEIGHT,
        xmin = (x <= 0) ? 0 : x-1, ymin = (y <= 0) ? 0 : y-1,//handle borders
        xmax = (x+2 > w) ? w : x+2, ymax = (y+2 > h) ? h : y+2;

    var env = gm.slice(ymin, ymax).map(function (row){//get environment array
        return row.slice(xmin, xmax);
    });

    env = [].concat.apply([], env);//flatten array

    return env.reduce(function (prev, cell) {//sum the neighbors
        return prev += cell;
    });
}

var Game = init("screen");

setInterval(function (){//repeat the steps every 50ms
    Game.gMap = step(Game.gMap);
    draw(Game);
}, STEP);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const STEP = 50;
const WIDTH = 200, HEIGHT = 100;

var w = WIDTH, h = HEIGHT,
    xmin = (x <= 0) ? 0 : x-1, ymin = (y <= 0) ? 0 : y-1,//handle borders
    xmax = (x+2 > w) ? w : x+2, ymax = (y+2 > h) ? h : y+2;
```

Be consistent. I usually recommend a `const`/`let`/`var` per variable and a line each to to make it easy to add and remove variables as needed. No surgical removal of variables in between commas and it's easy to spot the variables.

---

```
var Game = init("screen");

setInterval(function (){//repeat the steps every 50ms
    Game.gMap = step(Game.gMap);
    draw(Game);
}, STEP);
```

The problem with above is that it's not kosher in terms of functional programming. Each step is mutating `Game`, specifically `Game.gmap`. If I remember correctly, the functional way to create a game loop is to use recursion and construct a new game state on each step.

```
function gameLoop(gameState){
  draw(gameState);
  const newState = update(gameState);
  return gameLoop(newState);
}

return gameLoop(createInitialState());
```

The big difference is that you don't have `Game` or `Game.gmap` that mutates on each step. Each step takes in an entirely different state object than the previous. This is inefficient given existing JS data structures, but can be optimized using persistent data structures.

But JS has no TCO yet and you'll blow away the stack if you do it in existing engines (Node.js has it under a flag). The closest you can get to maintaining a similar code structure is by scheduling the next step asynchronously using `setTimeout`.

```
function gameLoop(gameState){
  draw(gameState);
  const newState = update(gameState);
  setTimeout(() => gameLoop(newState), STEP);
}

gameLoop(createInitialState());
```

---

```
function init(scr) {
    var cwObj = {
        canvas: document.getElementById(scr),//set up the graphics department
        gMap: new Array(HEIGHT).fill(new Array(WIDTH).fill(0))
    };
    draw(cwObj, ptr, 30, 60);
    step(cwObj.gMap);
    return cwObj;
}
```

I would suggest this `init` function only construct state. Drawing should just be a part of the game loop.

```
function createInitialState(){
  return { /* initial game state */ }
}
```

---

```
pattern.map(function (cur, i){
    cwObj.gMap[x + i] = insert(cwObj.gMap[x + i], cur, y);
    //insert() is a helper, just inserts at an index 
});

var out = '';
cwObj.gMap.map(function (cur) {     //create a string of active and 
    cur.map(function (cell) {       //inactive cells 
        if(cell) {out += "<b>&#9632;</b>";} else {out += "&#9632;";}
    });
    out += "<br>";
});
```

You are misusing `array.map`. `array.map` is meant to be a `1:1` transform of each item in an array into another. What you're doing here is a job for `array.forEach`. And since `array.forEach` does nothing but loop and return `undefined`, it has to be mutating something outside the callback, making it not functional.

Your first operation could be done with an `array.map` as it's essentially updating each value with a new value. You will have to replace the array, not mutate the existing one.

```
cwObj.gMap = pattern.map((current, i) => updatedValueForValueAt(i));
```

The second one appears to be a job for `array.reduce` as it is reducing the array into a single string.

```
const out = cwObj.gMap.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur.map(c => c? '<b>&#9632;</b>' : '&#9632;').join(''), '');
```

---

JS isn't entirely functional and you will often break rules where necessary. At best, you keep mutation to a minimal.

Comment: Very helpful answer, though some of the codes you supplied don't work. I can't create the whole map via going over the pattern array. It'll just return 3 arrays, no more. But you're absolutely right, I am misusing map.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to make it more functional:

1. Avoid `if` statements.
2. Prefer functions over setting temporary variables and making calculations based on those.
3. Rather than deal with exceptions, reframe the problem so that the exceptional circumstances are no longer exceptional.

Examples of 2. and 3. come up in the way you treat border cells.  An alternative is to get all the neighbors of every cell, and then filter out invalid ones.  Here's an example of that approach.  Also note: The main algorithm is a pure function -- we take in a grid and return a new grid.

```
function nextGeneration(grid) {

  var deltas       = [[-1,-1], [-1,0], [-1,1], [0 ,-1], [0 ,1], [1 ,-1], [1 ,0], [1 ,1]],
      m            = grid.length,
      n            = grid[0].length,
      validIndex   = (i,j) => i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < m && j < n,
      numNeighbors = (i,j) => deltas.map(d => [d[0]+i, d[1]+j])
                                    .filter(ij => validIndex.apply(null, ij))
                                    .reduce((m,ij) => m + grid[ij[0]][ij[1]], 0),
      nextLive     = n      => n == 2 || n == 3,
      nextDead     = n      => n == 3,
      show         = isLive => isLive ? 1 : 0;

  return grid.map( (row, i) => row.map( (isLive, j) => {
    var n = numNeighbors(i, j);
    return isLive ? show(nextLive(n)) : show(nextDead(n));
  }));
}

test = [
  [1,0,1,0],
  [1,1,1,0],
  [1,0,0,0]
];

console.log(nextGeneration(test));
```

On another note, you should use more descriptive names.  Short is ok, but it should be clear what they mean.

Comment: Perfectly functional! I appreciate that a lot. Although, sadly, this version is slower(1.5x) than the original.

Comment: If speed is a concern, I would probably do this quite differently, even if I were sticking to a functional style.  But note functional code will nearly always lose to hand-optimized procedural code in a speed contest.  Functional code buys you readability, simplicity, and maintainability, not speed (in general).  All that said,  you might try defining all the helper functions using `function` -- some engines will recreate them on every call as they are now.  Also define the deltas as a one-time constant outside the function.  You may see a boost after making those changes.

Comment: One final recommendation: If you are interested in exploring functional code in js more deeply, I highly recommend you check ramda.js and experiment with writing code like this in a point free style.  I could probably get my above sample to be half as long and even more readable with ramda....

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll try ramda.js, but I find it fair to accept the more detailed answer.